# Selecting a specific area not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I've tried this command

```
/testfor @p[x=775,y=58,z=726,dx=774,dy=56,dz=717]
```

but it doesn't work. How can I fix this? Any ideas?

Comment: it is worth noting that it was pretty obvious what you were asking. Close voters likely want more information, such as what you have tried, the context in which you are trying to get it to work, what you are actually trying to do etc.

Answer (score 5):

`dx`, `dy` and `dz` all specify a **difference** in x/y/z from the start point. If you think of it as a box with two sets of coordinates, it'd be from `(x,y,z)` to `(x+dx, y+dy, z+dz)`, **not** to `(dx, dy, dz)`. So, currently, your command's selection box goes from `(775, 58, 727)` to `(1549, 114, 2217)`.

Instead, for a box 1 deep 2 up and 9 along starting at `(774, 56, 717)`, your command should look like this:

```
/testfor @p[x=774,y=56,z=717,dx=1,dy=2,dz=9]
```